# error para obtener los datos del nodo de firebase en android studio

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Hola espero que me puedan ayudar.. tengo una bd en firebase quiero listar lo que contiene empresas pero me muestra este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo para obtener la data

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference empresaRef = database.getReference(FirebaseReference.EMPRESAS_REFERENCE);
    empresaRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            ArrayList<String> listtadoEmpresa = new ArrayList<>();

            for(DataSnapshot nodo : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Empresa empresa= nodo.getValue(Empresa.class);
                String nombre = empresa.getNombre();
                listtadoEmpresa.add(nombre);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("ERROR ", databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

y este es la bd de firebase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema parece estar en tus variables. Por ejemplo dentro del `for` hay una variable `empresa` que no existe realmente, debes declararla como variable local y luego hacer esto: `empresa= nodo.getValue(Empresa.class);` . El mensaje de error habla de otra variable `empresas` que parece estar en la misma situación. No la muestras aquí, pero por ahí debe andar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola podrías probar con este código, me avisas cualquier cosa

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference empresaRef = database.getReference().child(FirebaseReference.EMPRESAS_REFERENCE);
empresaRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        ArrayList<String> listtadoEmpresa = new ArrayList<>();

        for(DataSnapshot nodo : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Empresa empresa= nodo.getValue(Empresa.class);
            String nombre = empresa.getNombre();
            listtadoEmpresa.add(nombre);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e("ERROR ", databaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Explicacion: Si quieres entrar a empresas, este es un hijo de tu raíz por ende luego de llamar `getReference()` tienes que poner `.child("nombre del hijo")` que es donde esta "tu lista de empresas".

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder... acabo de probarlo y si funciona gracias... recién estoy entrando al mundo del android y no entendía mucho como funcionaba .child()..

Comment: Si te soluciono el problema, pon mi respuesta como valida :D